# Parsing page 1 and page 2 at the same time?

Tags: java, android, xml, rss, xmlpullparser

I would like to parse:

http://www.ddlvalley.cool/category/movies/feed/

and

http://www.ddlvalley.cool/category/movies/feed/?paged=2

at the same time-getting all the results from thoese two pages in the same 'page' -is it possible or do I have to make HttpurlConnection twice ?:S(I'm using xmlpullparser if that is of any concideraition)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible, since your program does not have control over the content which is served by the server.

Unless the server provides a link which will return the complete collection (http://www.ddlvalley.cool/category/movies/feed/?all) which I could not find, you will have to retrieve a list of possible pages and do a request for every one of them.

Off course you can create a class which agregates the results to one object.

Comment: ok-now I know anyway:) - thank you for Information and your time (y)